# Is it possible to convert fabricjs svg output to pdf without rasterizing?

Tags: pdf, svg, fabricjs, vector-graphics

We are building a web app where the user can make a design by using fabric.js and at the end he should receive a pdf file with his work.

At first, we tried to use JSPDF because it was prefered to have a cliente-side solution. However by doing pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL(),...) we are rasterizing the design.

In second place, we tried server side solution using WKHTMLTOPDF, sending canvas.toSVG(), but there are some issues with fonts and shapes rendering.

The designs are complex as they can have text, shapes, images and svg.

We also tried INKSCAPE (inkscape --without-gui --export-pdf ...), MPDF and MUPDF without good results. IMAGEMAGICK is not a solution has it also rasterize the design.

The main goal is to get a vector pdf, where it's possible to increase size and where the elements of the design are selectable, and if possible that pdf should be ready to print (300 dpi and cmyk)

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369596/3551786)

Comment: @Durga, thank you for your comment. However the solution in this link is using pdf.addImage() and by doing so it is rasterizing the work.

Comment: In that pdf document or to canvas?

Comment: @Durga, I think that in both. In your exemple, when you use canvas.toDataURL() we no longer have vector nature from this point forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible using TCPDF library. 
Please check this ImageSVG api for more information for converting SVG to PDF.
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_058/

Answer (score 0):

Export the canvas to svg and use pdflib to make the pdf.

You can find an exemple here:https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/graphics/starter-svg/

Comment: thank you for this answer.  However i have started to try using tcpdf and i'm putting all my efforts on it.  At the present it will be very complicated to restart everything to test your suggesting of using pdflib.  In the future i will update this with my final result (with tcpdf if everything goes ok or with pdflib if the first fails). Thank you again

Comment: Not sure what features have tcpdf  but I think pdflib is better. It support even icc colors and cmyk. if you thinking using pdflib in the future here is a link to cookbook :http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-9.1.1-tutorial.pdf. On page 211 you can find Unsupported SVG Features for pdflib

Comment: @RicardoCarvalho are you using tile patterns with tcpdf?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure what you mean about "tile patterns", however i have done some tests like this:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r5jtLc7h/11/       As you can see the canvas.toSVG() works fine, however when i send it to the server TCPDF doesn't render the circle and outputs the full image.

Comment: @Daniel, see also https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/feature-requests/257/ and Nicola Asuni (TCPDF creator) comment where he says that TCPDF doesn't support yet SVG with patterns.